# Stack Data and remove 0s/NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given following table `order_size`:

```
Symbol      BAX  BTP  CT  D  DX  ESTX50  GBM  GBP  GBS  GE  I  LE  NZD  S  ZL  
Date                                                                            
2016-03-03    0    0  -2  0   0       0    0    0    0   0  0   0    0  0   0   
2016-03-04  -12    0   0  0   0       0    0    0    0   1  0   0   -1  0   0   
2016-03-07    0    0   0  0  -1       0    1   -1    4  -1  1   0    1  1   0   
2016-03-08    0    0   0  0   0       0    0    0    0   0  0   0   -1  0   0   
2016-03-10    0    0   0  0   0       0    0    1   -1   0  0   0    0  0   0   
2016-03-11    0    0   0  0   0       0   -1   -1   -1   0 -1   0    1 -1   0   
2016-03-14    0    0   0  0   0       0    0    0    0   0  0   0   -1  1   0   
2016-03-15   -1    0   0  0   0       0    0    0    0   1  0   0    1  0   0   
2016-03-17    0    0   0  0   0       0    0    0    0  -1  0   0    0  0  -1
```

I need to convert this into a stacked view, ending up with a layout such as this:
`Date | Symbol | Value`, where value isn't `0`, meaning all entries are dropped. 
If I use `df.stack()`, it converts it to a `pd.TimeSeries`, which isn't what I want (since I will be lacking a third column).

```
Date        Symbol
2016-03-03  BAX        0
            BTP        0
            CT        -2
            D          0
            DX         0
            ESTX50     0
            GBM        0
            GBP        0
```

Which makes it seemingly impossible to run `order_size.loc[:, (order_size.Value != 0).any(axis=0)]` to remove the 0s (since `Values` isn't a column in that `pd.Series`).

**Edit**

`order_size.replace('0', np.NaN)`before running `df.stack()` almost does the trick, but a `pd.Series` still isn't desirable, as I do need that third column `Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first replace all values equal `0` to `NaN` and then use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df != 0
              BAX    BTP     CT      D     DX ESTX50    GBM    GBP    GBS  \
Date                                                                        
2016-03-03  False  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False   
2016-03-04   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
2016-03-07  False  False  False  False   True  False   True   True   True   
2016-03-08  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
2016-03-10  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   
2016-03-11  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   
2016-03-14  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
2016-03-15   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   
2016-03-17  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   

               GE      I     LE    NZD      S     ZL  
Date                                                  
2016-03-03  False  False  False  False  False  False  
2016-03-04   True  False  False   True  False  False  
2016-03-07   True   True  False   True   True  False  
2016-03-08  False  False  False   True  False  False  
2016-03-10  False  False  False  False  False  False  
2016-03-11  False   True  False   True   True  False  
2016-03-14  False  False  False   True   True  False  
2016-03-15   True  False  False   True  False  False  
2016-03-17   True  False  False  False  False   True
```

```
print df[df != 0]
             BAX  BTP   CT   D   DX  ESTX50  GBM  GBP  GBS   GE    I  LE  NZD  \
Date                                                                            
2016-03-03   NaN  NaN -2.0 NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN   
2016-03-04 -12.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN -1.0   
2016-03-07   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN -1.0     NaN  1.0 -1.0  4.0 -1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0   
2016-03-08   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN -1.0   
2016-03-10   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  1.0 -1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN   
2016-03-11   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN -1.0 -1.0 -1.0  NaN -1.0 NaN  1.0   
2016-03-14   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN -1.0   
2016-03-15  -1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN  1.0   
2016-03-17   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN -1.0  NaN NaN  NaN   

              S   ZL  
Date                  
2016-03-03  NaN  NaN  
2016-03-04  NaN  NaN  
2016-03-07  1.0  NaN  
2016-03-08  NaN  NaN  
2016-03-10  NaN  NaN  
2016-03-11 -1.0  NaN  
2016-03-14  1.0  NaN  
2016-03-15  NaN  NaN  
2016-03-17  NaN -1.0
```

```
df1 = df[df != 0].stack().reset_index()
#set custom column names
df1.columns = ['Date','Symbol','Value']
print df1
          Date Symbol  Value
0   2016-03-03     CT   -2.0
1   2016-03-04    BAX  -12.0
2   2016-03-04     GE    1.0
3   2016-03-04    NZD   -1.0
4   2016-03-07     DX   -1.0
5   2016-03-07    GBM    1.0
6   2016-03-07    GBP   -1.0
7   2016-03-07    GBS    4.0
8   2016-03-07     GE   -1.0
9   2016-03-07      I    1.0
10  2016-03-07    NZD    1.0
11  2016-03-07      S    1.0
12  2016-03-08    NZD   -1.0
13  2016-03-10    GBP    1.0
14  2016-03-10    GBS   -1.0
15  2016-03-11    GBM   -1.0
16  2016-03-11    GBP   -1.0
17  2016-03-11    GBS   -1.0
18  2016-03-11      I   -1.0
19  2016-03-11    NZD    1.0
20  2016-03-11      S   -1.0
21  2016-03-14    NZD   -1.0
22  2016-03-14      S    1.0
23  2016-03-15    BAX   -1.0
24  2016-03-15     GE    1.0
25  2016-03-15    NZD    1.0
26  2016-03-17     GE   -1.0
27  2016-03-17     ZL   -1.0
```

Another solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.replace({0:np.nan})
df1 = df[df != 0].stack().reset_index()
#set custom column names
df1.columns = ['Date','Symbol','Value']
print df1
          Date Symbol  Value
0   2016-03-03     CT   -2.0
1   2016-03-04    BAX  -12.0
2   2016-03-04     GE    1.0
3   2016-03-04    NZD   -1.0
4   2016-03-07     DX   -1.0
5   2016-03-07    GBM    1.0
6   2016-03-07    GBP   -1.0
7   2016-03-07    GBS    4.0
8   2016-03-07     GE   -1.0
9   2016-03-07      I    1.0
10  2016-03-07    NZD    1.0
11  2016-03-07      S    1.0
12  2016-03-08    NZD   -1.0
13  2016-03-10    GBP    1.0
14  2016-03-10    GBS   -1.0
15  2016-03-11    GBM   -1.0
16  2016-03-11    GBP   -1.0
17  2016-03-11    GBS   -1.0
18  2016-03-11      I   -1.0
19  2016-03-11    NZD    1.0
20  2016-03-11      S   -1.0
21  2016-03-14    NZD   -1.0
22  2016-03-14      S    1.0
23  2016-03-15    BAX   -1.0
24  2016-03-15     GE    1.0
25  2016-03-15    NZD    1.0
26  2016-03-17     GE   -1.0
27  2016-03-17     ZL   -1.0
```

Comment: Please check solution - you need replace `0` to `NaN` or all values not `0` to `NaN`?

Comment: I need to replace `0` with `NaN`!